# how to install an enterprise app without having installation confirmation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, app-store

I have a requirement to develop an iOS app(installer app) that can be used to download & install other enterprise iOS apps.The scenario is,Once I have installed the installer app,the server will send silent push notifications to the app.Once the push notification reached the app,it should automatically download & install the corresponding enterprise app from the server.I have uploaded sample enterprise applications to the server and tried to initiate them using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=serveraddress/application.plist"]];
```

Using this functionality anyways,I can download & install the other app but it asks user's permission for installing the app.Is there any work around to skip this prompting and directly install the app?

Also is there anyway to initiate the above statement,even if app is not in the iOS dashboard(minimized) once the push notification is obtained.

Comment: I really doubt that you can skip asking user's permission. You should be using an MDM service for your purpose (https://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/management.html)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions, an itms-services request will always ask the user permission. The install modal is being generated by a system call and not your app, so unfortunately there's no cutesy way of using (for example) the KIF framework to simulate a button push in the confirmation dialog. There is currently no way to initiate an itms-services request when the app is in the background, the system request isn't queued, it's ignored because the app isn't in the foreground. iOS7 introduced the ability for a forced install capability for MDMs, which I believe can be a silent install. I haven't had a chance to play around with iOS9 much yet, but I doubt that it includes silent install without an MDM.